# Android react native app keeps stopping in release mode

Tags: android, react-native

Here is the error log I got from monitor when I try to launch the application

> 07-24 09:26:08.101: E/ReactNativeJS(26640): undefined is not an object  (evaluating 'r.default')
>      07-24 09:26:08.112: E/ReactNativeJS(26640): Module AppRegistry is not a     registered callable module (calling runApplication)
>      07-24 09:26:08.120: E/com.marianhello.logging.UncaughtExceptionLogger(26640): FATAL EXCEPTION:

Am using react-native

```
"react": "16.3.1",
"react-native": "^0.56.0",
```

Comment: How is Java involved in this question?

Comment: Are you using React navigation in your project?

Comment: Yes  am using react navigation with paystack payment gateway

Answer (score 0):

So the cause of error is just stupid.

The issue with **React-Navigation** **In node_modules/react-navigation/src/navigators/DrawerNavigator.js** there is imported **TabRouter**, which seems like component (starts with upper case), but in reality is just function, so when the code reaches const contentRouter = TabRouter(routeConfigs, tabsConfig); it throws that error because it does not resolve it as function? It does not even run it. This is some new babel config stuff or something, which is just weird space of js for me...

So one way to fix this is to rename all **TabRouter** in that file to **tabRouter**. I hate to modify node_modules files but this is only way that I found to fix this error. Its working for me.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve this issue by downgrading my react native to "react-native": "^0.54.0" from "react-native": "^0.56.0" that i install initially.
and everything works fine.